# Problem with the precision

Tags: plotting, matrix, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to plot eigenvalues of a matrix.
I get some errors like “precision may be lost”.
As a result, there are some unwanted jumps in the plot.
Any suggestion of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into numerical precision trouble. Use exact numbers instead. With all your definitions, change the calculation of `eigenvalues` to:

```
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[Rationalize[H, 0]]
```

You can then plot them as you expected, although the following naïve plot is remarkably slow:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate@N@eigenvalues, {bx, -0.2, 0.2}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"B", "y"}
]
```

[image: eigenvalues - no zero crossings]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Would you please explain briefly what does "Evaluate@N@" do in the last line? I could not google it.

Comment: @sarasam The results from Eigenvalues are symbolic and the plotting was very slow. `N@eigenvalues` turns them into machine-precision entities. Because of the `Hold` attribute of `Plot`, I added `Evaluate` to force pre-evaluation of its argument, and make sure that Plot was dealing with the machine precision argument. I am not sure that it made a great difference in terms of plotting speed. You could remove it and see how king it takes to plot, I.e. `Plot[eigenvalues, ...]`.